# How to split axios functions and components in vue3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I think it is better to split the axios commands and the vue components.

This is my directory structure:

```
src
  api
    - products.js
  components
    - Products.vue
```

`products.js`

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const listProducts = () => {
  const headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" };
  let url = "http://localhost:8001/api/v1/products";
  const response = axios.get(url, headers);
  return response.data
}

export default {
  listProducts,
}
```

`Products.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <div>{{ products }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import { listProducts } from "@/api/products.js"

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      products: {},
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getProducts();
  },
  methods: {
     getProducts() {
       this.products = listProducts();
     }
   }
}
</script>
```

But `this.products` is undefined. I tried some stuff with async and await, but nothing works.

And what would be best practice in vue3?

Comment: Axios is async hence you will need to use some `async/await` here. Otherwise, you will get an empty result because the promise is not resolved yet indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`axios.get()` returns a `Promise`, so `response` in the following line is actually a `Promise` (not the Axios response itself):

```js
const listProducts = () => {
  ⋮
  const response = axios.get(url, headers);
  return response.data // ❌ `response` is a `Promise`
}
```

To get the response, you can await the result of the `axios.get()` call:

```js
                       
const listProducts = async () => {
  ⋮                   
  const response = await axios.get(url, headers);
  return response.data
}
```

Similarly, this updated `listProducts()` function now returns a `Promise` because it's `async`. Your component now must await the result of `listProducts()`:

```js
// Products.vue
export default {
  ⋮
  methods: {
       
     async getProducts() {
                         
       this.products = await listProducts();
     }
   }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-load-fetched-data?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FProducts.vue)

Comment: Thank your very much! Should I use try/except or something, if my api doesn't answer?

Comment: Yes, a `try`/`catch` is recommended.